# Using Cauchy Integral Formula: $\small\displaystyle \int_c \frac{e^{-z^2}}{z^2}dz$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration

I am going over the solutions to previous problems in order to prepare for a test.  I am having a hard time understanding even basic applications of Cauchy's Integral Formula.

For example, I have tried to solve for the solution to the integral $$\int_c \frac{e^{-z^2}}{z^2}dz$$ where C is any positively-oriented simple closed contour surrounding the origin.

The solutions simply states that $$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_C \frac{e^{-z^2}}{z^2}dz = (e^{-z^2})'|_{z=0} = 0$$ by Cauchy.

How is Cauchy applied here?  What are the steps taken to get from one side of the = to the other?

Comment: See [Cauchy's Differentiation Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula#Theorem).

Comment: @GitGud That gives me the left side, but how do I get to the right side of the =?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** By [Cauchy Integral Formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CauchyIntegralFormula.html) we have

$$f'(z_0) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_C \frac{f(z)}{(z-z_0)^2} dz$$

Let $z_0 = 0$ and $f(z) = e^{-z^2}$.

Comment: I was able to apply Cauchy's Differentiation Formula to get to this point.  I am having trouble seeing how this helps the situation though.  I can't seem to figure out what steps to take from this point to get to the solution.

Comment: Have you computed the derivative of $f(z)$? Once you finish, take $f'(0)$.

Comment: That is what I have been missing this whole time.  Thanks.

Comment: You're most welcome!